# Excel VBA R1C1 formula for SUM xlUp

Tags: excel, sum, excel-r1c1-notation, vba

This code will sum the 6 cells above it in Column P of the last row+1 of the data dump.

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-6]C:R[-1]C)"
```

I need help with the R[-6]C part. The dump can have variable rows and I want to always sum all the way up to P2.

How can I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the absolute version `R2C` in place of `R[-6]C`

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"
```

Now it will always refer to the second row of that column.